# Form data can not be updated

Tags: php, laravel, insert-update

[![fields keep old values][1]][1]

I am trying to **update** a form with name , email and role after I set roles and permissions using Laratrust,
my userController:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
 {
    dd($request->all());  // here  Array of data is successfully updated
    $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required|unique:users,email',
        'role_id'=>'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $user->update($request->all());
     $user->syncRoles($request->role_id); 
    session()->flash('success','Data updated successfully');
      return redirect()->route('dashboard.users.index');   //failed to redirect
 }  //end of Update Fn
```

**My edit.blade has this:**

```
 <form  method="POST" action="{{route('dashboard.users.update', $user->id)}}">
        @method('PUT')
```

Note: when I dd $request it gives array of data updated suucessfully except when I dd after the line:

```
$user->syncRoles($request->role_id);    //revise admin
     dd($request->all());
```

*I got the following error:*
**ErrorException Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**
**C:\xampp\htdocs\mynet\vendor\santigarcor\laratrust\src\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait.php:343**

Comment: what error your r getting.?

Comment: no error appears, only same view with same date without update, even redirect to index not executed

Comment: thenk please check action route your dd() should work

Comment: route is OK with create and delete

Comment: i did not found any route which is calling `update()` function can you show that.?

Comment: <form  method="POST" action="{{route('dashboard.users.update', $user->id)}}">
            @method('PUT')

Comment: can you put we.php with `dashboard.users.update` route in question

Comment: redirecting back() is normally due to occur for validation.. Did you check the fields properly

Comment: plz what do you mean with  check the fields properly?

Comment: @shaza he is saying may be you data is not valid and you are getting error in same page but you havn't print any data in blde so  you are not seen any error

Comment: I think data is valid because both create and delete functions are working properly.

Comment: dd works:       array:5 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "name" => "Ahmed"
  "email" => "ahmed.aly@gmail.com"
  "role_id" => "10"
  "_token" => "m3Qn8BSf99qFQn0wzg1SMzKbJwbnGV9TVxUtq4FG"
]

Comment: Did you add the old value using a form?

Comment: What happens if you pass only email and name without role_id and _token to the update function?

Comment: yes i use: value="{{old('name', $user->name)}}"  to keep old value in case not changed by user, I tried to remove to see if it is the cause But found same result, No update excuted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
 {

    $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required|unique:users,email',
        'role_id'=>'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $user->attachRole($request->role_id);
    $user->update($request->all());
    $user->refresh(); // Reload User or $user->load('roles');
    session()->flash('success','Data updated successfully');
      return redirect()->route('dashboard.users.index');  
 }
```

Comment: I think you should pass the updated roles in syncRoles() function.
 `$roles = $user->getRoleNames();`
`$user->syncRoles($roles); `

Comment: I had to remove this line:          // $user->syncRoles($request->role_id);    //revise admin
so name and email can be updated but CAN NOT update Role

Comment: @Harbal I got Call to undefined method App\User::getRoleNames()

Answer (score 0):

Code should be:
1-        $user->attachRole($request->role_id); ins upsate function
2-        Index blade should have:

```
 @foreach($user->roles as $role)
       <h5>{{$role->name}}</h5>
 @endforeach


public function update(Request $request, User $user)
 {

    $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required',
        'role_id'=>'required|numeric',
    ]);
    $user->name = $request->Name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->attachRole($request->role_id);

    $user->update($request->all());
    $user->refresh(); // Reload User or $user->load('roles');
    session()->flash('success','Data updated successfully');
      return redirect()->route('dashboard.users.index');
 }  //end of updates
```